# VirtualBox ping between guests

Tags: virtualbox

I have two Windows 10 VMs in Virtualbox (on a Windows host).

I put both of them on the same internal network, changed their IPs to be fixed (1.136.1.1 and 1.136.1.70 with a net mask of 255.0.0.0).

And when I try to ping between them it just doesn't work and I can't find why.

Are there any configuration I might be missing ?

Comment: Is the network adapter set to public or private network? If you don't have a gateway/router Windows has no MAC address to identify the network and may set it to public (which block incoming ICM messages and hence ping wil not work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Robert comment was the right solution.

Windows by default set my network as a public network in which network discovery is disabled and the VMs can not ping each other.

I couldn't find a way to force my network to be private so I enabled network discovery on both VMs and now the ping works.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you are using Bridged or NAT networking, your machines should be using DHCP. Certainly NAT uses DHCP for its machines.

If you wish to use Static IP addressing, you need to switch to Bridged Networking and then assign Static Address on the Router range outside the host computer.